# Method compareDocumentPosition unsupported only in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

In one of my web pages, I am using the following line of JavaScript:

```
return !!(a.compareDocumentPosition(b) & 16);
```

However, *only in IE9*, I am getting the following error:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'compareDocumentPosition'

Other browsers work fine. Does anyone know of an available fix or workaround for this?

Comment: Look at http://ejohn.org/blog/comparing-document-position/ for an IE solution.

Comment: Internet Explorer supports `compareDocumentPosition` only in IE9 mode. Make sure you have `<!doctype html>` at the beginning of your markup and `document.documentMode` returns `9`.

Comment: @pimvdb IE9 supports `compareDocumentPosition(...)` (see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975125%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Your site is a workaround for IE less then version 9.

Comment: @scessor: You're completely correct, I didn't expect that.

Answer (score 1):

> Internet Explorer supports compareDocumentPosition only in IE9 mode. Make sure you have  at the beginning of your markup and document.documentMode returns 9